# Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'

Tags: android, build.gradle

```
    > Task :app:minifyReleaseWithR8
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Ignoring option: -dump","sources":[{"file":"/Users/merlin720/easycan/gitlab/android-app/app/proguard-rules.pro","position":{"startLine":47,"startColumn":0,"startOffset":1295,"endColumn":21,"endOffset":1316}}],"tool":"R8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class: com.alipay.sdk.app.H5PayCallback","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class: com.facebook.imagepipeline.request.BasePostprocessor","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class: com.bun.miitmdid.core.IIdentifierListener","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Library class android.test.AndroidTestRunner extends program class junit.runner.BaseTestRunner","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Library class android.test.InstrumentationTestCase extends program class junit.framework.TestCase","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Library class android.test.AndroidTestCase extends program class junit.framework.TestCase","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Library class android.test.InstrumentationTestSuite extends program class junit.framework.TestSuite","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}
```

> Task :app:minifyReleaseWithR8 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.

  > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

when i update android studio to 3.0 and

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files

    //美团多渠道
    classpath 'com.meituan.android.walle:plugin:1.1.6'
}
```

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me added to gradle

```
"implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'"
```

Comment: helped in my case!

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the exact same issue and could not find any solution for now. I reverted back to Gradle Plugin 3.5.3 and gradle-5.4.1-all.zip for now...

Comment: I reverted back to 3.5.3 too.

Answer (score 0):

for me , it seems caused by "inifyEnabled  = true" when R8 shrink or minify codes. after it is set false like this below  , it builds successfully.

```
buildTypes {
release {
  isMinifyEnabled = false
  proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
}
```

}

Comment: "distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-bin.zip"
gradle verision  both  8.1 and  8.3 cannot build success when  "minifyEnabled = true"

Comment: Above answer dosent works. Android Studio throws error as minifyEnabled is needed as true.